# Does it break the rules if i give Reward for being connected to Google Play Game service?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I have read the google play game service rules and can't find the answer. Maybe my English isn't that good, so my question is :

Does it break the rules if i give Reward for being connected to Google Play Game service ? The reward would not imbalance the gameplay, this is just to say "thanks" to the players that share their score on leaderboard.

Is it permitted by google to do such things?  Also is it possible to ask directly the developer of the the google game service? Can't find their email.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: I'm not seeing any precedent of game developers facing repercussions for rewarding online engagement. Login rewards are pretty common in games with an online component. However, something like daily [Quests](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quests) would probably be more effective in boosting player engagement (provided you can continually provide bits of new content for your players to enjoy).